# iOS embeded UIImagePickerController'S Use Photo button not working after taking photo

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

It is an iPhone app and I have an assistant view which is always on top of the window(can expand and minimise). There are a few buttons inside the view that allow me to switch between capturing image, capturing video and recording audio. In app delegate it looks like:

```
[self.window addSubview:assistantFloatingViewController.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
self.window.frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
```

Then add `UIImagePickerController` when click capture image button inside the assistant view:

```
- (void)presentImagePicker{
    UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController =    [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePickerController.delegate = self;
    imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    imagePickerController.mediaTypes = @[(__bridge NSString *) kUTTypeImage];

    [self moveFromViewController:self.currentContentViewController ToViewController:imagePickerController];
    self.currentContentViewController = imagePickerController;
}

- (void)moveFromViewController:(UIViewController *)fromVC ToViewController:(UIViewController *)toVC {
   [fromVC willMoveToParentViewController:nil];

   [self addChildViewController:toVC];

   [fromVC.view removeFromSuperview];
   [fromVC removeFromParentViewController];

   [self.view addSubview:toVC.view];

   [toVC.view alignToView:self.containerView];

   [toVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];

   self.currentContentViewController = toVC;
}
```

> The problem is after I took an image, Retake and User Photo buttons cannot be tapped (no response ).

What have I done wrong here? Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I checked in view debugger. The image picker controller is the top most view.

Answer (score 0):

Replace last two line of your code

```
[self moveFromViewController:self.currentContentViewController ToViewController:imagePickerController];
self.currentContentViewController = imagePickerController;
```

with this one,

```
[self presentViewController:imgPicker animated:YES completion:^{

     // Your code
}];
```

Comment: Thx for the reply. However, I need the image picker to be inside my custom view, not in full screen(iPhone app). I might implement a custom overlay for the image picker and disable the default controls, which seems working from testing.